# Using $(body) to add single event listener on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

So i came across a code like below:

```
  var bindEvents = function () {

    $("body").on('click', "a.class1, input.class2, button.class3", function () {
      sendEvents($(this));
    });

  }
```

And i was wondering why would someone bind the event on `body` here.

Can't we just do it by directly adding events on `a`, `input` and `button` elements like this:

```
  var bindEvents = function () {

    $("a.class1, input.class2, button.class3").on('click', function () {
      sendEvents($(this));
    });

  }
```

Is there any reason why one would use the 1st approach?

Comment: What's done here is called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and used to bind event on element which do not exist on the initial page load

Comment: Why don't u give one more same class to each of them and using one class name ?

Comment: Not exact duplicate but the relevant answer should cover and explain the subject of event delegation

Comment: To complement @AlonEitan 's link, this answer provides some more info on why you need event delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @pc_coder looks like it's a contrived example for demonstration purposes.  It's unlikely (I hope...) that OP has `class1` etc

Comment: @pc_coder yeah the actual code is somewhat different so ...

Comment: @AlonEitan To some extent yes. I am looking at the points mentioned under "Here are times when event delegation is required or advantageous:" part in the accepted answer. 

1)The elements are not being generated dynamically so that is probably not the reason. 

2)However there are a lot of elements to bind this event to, so 2nd reason might be it. But it doesn't completely explain why this approach is good in this case.